# Why do I need the @Configuration annotation when using WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to learn websocket and follow the guide. It advises starting with:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
 public class MyConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS();
     }

     @Override
     public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
         registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");
         registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app/");
     }
 }
```

And I don't really understand the meaning of the annotation `@Configuration`.

As I understand it, the container finds information about the Bean in it, but if only @override is used in this class, then what does it do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime...

@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

Add this annotation to an @Configuration class to enable broker-backed messaging over WebSocket using a higher-level messaging sub-protocol...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/EnableWebSocketMessageBroker.html

That mean without @Configuration,  @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker will be ignored by spring container. So WebSocket will not be enabled.